# Cocoa and Cocoa Touch: is an object on the dictionary?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary

I thought it would be simpler to find if an object in on a dictionary, but it appears it is not.

I have a NSMutableDictionary with just one key named "products".

I have several products added to the dictionary dynamically, using something like

```
[myDict addObject:@"banana" forKey:@"products"];
[myDict addObject:@"orange" forKey:@"products"];
[myDict addObject:@"grapes" forKey:@"products"];
```

etc.

At some point I would like to know if, for example, banana is on the dictionary.

Is there a way to do that? I mean, just to know if an object is on the dictionary?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put whatever you want as the object.  Using objectForKey will return `nil` if the object is not in the dictionary and will return the object if it is.  You can use it like this:

```
[myDict addObject:@"WHATEVER YOU WANT" forKey:@"banana"];
[myDict addObject:@"WHATEVER YOU WANT" forKey:@"orange"];
[myDict addObject:@"WHATEVER YOU WANT" forKey:@"grapes"];
..
..
..
if ([myDict objectForKey:@"banana"]) {
  // I have a banana
} 
if ([myDict objectForKey:@"orange"]) {
  // I have an orange
} 
if ([myDict objectForKey:@"grapes"]) {
  // I have grapes
}
```

Comment: If you think that'll work for you, why not just use an NSSet?

Answer (score 7):

You're misunderstanding how dictionaries work.  Dictionaries store a *single* value for a *single* key.  So after your code runs, `myDict` will hold a single key-value pair: `@"products"` => `@"grapes"`.  If you need a key to point to multiple objects, then your key will need to point to an `NSMutableArray` (or `NSMutableSet` if you don't care about order), and then you add and remove things from the `NSMutableArray` rather than from the dictionary.

If this is going to be the basic structure for everything in your dictionary, you might want to consider making a wrapper for your dictionary, like so:

```
//DDMutableMultiValueDictionary.h
@interface DDMutableMultiValueDictionary : NSObject {
  NSMutableDictionary * dict;
}

- (void) addObject:(id)value forKey:(id)key;
- (void) removeObject:(id)value forKey:(id)key;
- (BOOL) containsObject:(id)value forKey:(id)key;

@end

//DDMutableMultiValueDictionary.m
#import "DDMutableMultiValueDictionary.h"

@implementation DDMutableMultiValueDictionary

- (id) init {
  if (self = [super init]) {
    dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void) dealloc {
  [dict release];
  [super dealloc];
}

- (void) addObject:(id)value forKey:(id)key {
  NSMutableArray * values = [dict objectForKey:key];
  if (values == nil) {
    values = [NSMutableArray array];
    [dict setObject:values forKey:key]
  }
  [values addObject:value];
}

- (void) removeObject:(id)value forKey:(id)key {
  NSMutableArray * values = [dict objectForKey:key];
  [values removeObject:value];
}

- (BOOL) containsObject:(id)value forKey:(id)key {
  NSMutableArray * values = [dict objectForKey:key];
  return [values containsObject:value];
}

@end
```

That isn't complete by any means, but it gives you an idea of how you could make it.

Comment: Or just making a model object for whatever has products, and giving it a `products` property by which it owns the array or set.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the other posters that you may be misunderstanding how dictionaries work. But on the off chance it's useful, here's how you could look to see if a specific object is present as a value, and for which key(s):

```
// assume the object you're looking for is in the variable myValue
NSArray *keys = [myDict allKeysForObject:myValue];
if( [keys count] ) {
  // do whatever ...
}
```

Comment: +1 It's not often I see a valid use case for `allKeysForObject:`.  I've never used it myself.